# Why does Gmail save a chat in Sent Mail?

Tags: gmail, chat

I use Gmail. I have a chat conversation in Sent Mail, not in Inbox! Sent Mail means email, but I have a chat there like 1 email-1 line of a chat. It annoys me...

I have Conversation view off. I have never seen that problem with Conversation view off.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

[Create a filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en). Using `in:sent` you can get all e-mails in the "Sent Mail" category, then match for text contained or whatever makes your chat logs unique and set the filter to apply the label `Inbox` which should move them to your inbox.

This should mean that as soon as a chat log shows up in Sent Mail, it's moved to the Inbox.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to create any filters. Just simply click "more" in chat window and click first position "go off record". My English is not perfect but at least I know how to use computer. Good day;)

Comment: But what if you don't want to go off the record?